# How to set the value of hidden field using Razor

Tags: javascript, html, razor

Hi I am very new to Razor, and I am trying to reset the value of a hidden field, so that it would fire the onchange event. However the code below is not working, the value of the hidden field - trigger does not get changed.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function dosomething()
  {
     alert("something");
  }
 </script> 

 <input id="trigger" name="trigger" value="1" type="hidden"   onchange="dosomething()" />

  @Html.Hidden("trigger", "9");      

 }
```

Comment: If you look at the rendered HTML I think you will find that you now have TWO hidden controls named `trigger`, once from the `<input>` tag and once from the `@Html.Hidden` call.

Comment: so how would I reset the value in this case without using JavaScript, thanks

Comment: I am a little bit confused -- What is action/event is supposed to cause the value to change?  Usually when we have a hidden field we are keeping some non-editable value like an ID/Key around so we can pass it back to the server on some action or condition.  Sometimes a value from another control in the markup is retrieved and then we  sets the hidden control's value to this retrieved value -- BUT this tends to be Javascript work.  Can you tell us more about what you mean when you say `how would I *reset* the value` and also why NO JavaScript is important for your case?

Comment: I meant how would you change the value of the hidden field in this case on the server side rather than using javascript. And the hidden field already exists in the HTML.

Comment: thank you for your response, the reason why i can't use JavaScript is b/c for some reason the JavaScript does not load in the Layout.cshtml, but the C# code does. When I say reset I meant changing the value of the hidden field, or any field (eg. textbox).